# How to get complete directory ?

Tags: android, file

Is it possible to get the complete data of a directory?
I only can get one file:

```
 String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
  .getPath() + "/Test/****Complete*****";
```

Comment: You have to give some more context. You are storing the location of a file in a string right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `File` object, which despite it's name can also be a directory.

```
File directory = new File("my/path");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().list()`  will return an array of files in that firectory.

THere's also a version that takes a filter parameter